# jQuery Plugin variable availability

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Today for the first time, I ran into a problem where variables were being mixed up with multiple instances of jQuery plug-ins.

A simple version of my plug-in can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/jydzB/2/

I want to be able to simply create a timer in a plugin, and access the variable "myTimer" in another method within the plugin. In this case, to destroy it. However, I thought for sure that creating variables like I did below with "myTimer" made that variable available only in that class/plugin? Am I wrong? How do I use variables within a plugin? I know I could store them in $obj.data('',''), but that doesn't make sense to do that when you could simply store it in a var.

You will see that when you run the jsFiddle script, it doesn't destroy the timer.

Simple HTML

```
Write a line every five seconds... destroy it after 10:<br />
<hr />
<div id='myDiv' style='border: solid 1px #000;float:left;'></div>
<div id='myDiv2' style='border: solid 1px #f00;float:right;'></div>
```

jQuery Plugin

```
if (jQuery) (
    function (jQuery) {        
        var myTimer;            
        var methods = {
            init: function () {
                return this.each(function () {
                    var $obj = $(this);
                    var data = $obj.data('init');
                    if (!data) {
                        myTimer = setInterval(function(){
                            writeLine($obj)
                        }, 1000);
                        $obj.data('init', true);
                        $obj.data('cnt',0);
                    }
                });        
            },
            destroy: function () {
                var $obj = $(this);
                $obj.data('init', false);
                clearInterval(myTimer);
                $obj.append("Destroyed!");
            }
        };        
        $.fn.timeIt = function (method) {                   
            if (methods[method]) {
                return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
                return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
            } else {
                $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.timeIt');
            }
        };
    }
)(jQuery);

$('#myDiv').timeIt();
$('#myDiv2').timeIt();

function writeLine(cObj) {
    cObj.data('cnt',cObj.data('cnt')+1);
    cObj.append("Another line written...(" + cObj.data('cnt') + ")<Br />");    
    if(cObj.data('cnt')>=10){
        cObj.timeIt('destroy');
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think usage of a variable scoped at that level is fine, aside from the fact that you're assigning the value of myTimer inside of your `each` (different context each time). If you remove the second wire-up (`$('#myDiv2').timeIt();`) it works like a champ. Storing the variable with the instance would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain 'storing it with the instance'?

Comment: Storing it with the instance would be (essentially) adding it to the `$obj.data` collection like so: `$obj.data('pid', myTimer);`. Then in the `destroy` method, clear it like so: `clearInterval($obj.data('pid'));`. Updated your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/jydzB/3/

Comment: Great. I assumed .data wasnt intended for that, but it makes sense. Thanks!